# Couldnot access the controller method from javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having a scenario where Forgot password is displayed in a Modal when click on link from sessions -> new / signin form.
Now I need to add validation for "check if email exists". 
For this I added a route, method in users_controller, script in sessions/new as shown below.
With alerts and rails log I came to know that, when I click on button it is not going to users_controller/ checkemail method 
and every email is showing as "Email doesnot exists".
Please help me what the mistake I have done?

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions'}, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout" }

get "/checkemail" => "users#checkemail", as: :checkemail
```

users_controller.rb:

```
 def checkemail
    puts "****************************************"
    @checkemail = User.find_by_email(params[:checkemail])
    if @checkemail.present?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: "0" }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: "1" }
      end
    end
  end
```

app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :remote => true, :format => :json, :html => { :id => 'password_reset' }) do |f| %>
        <input type="hidden" id="email_flag" value="0">
          <%= f.inputs do %>        
              <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Your email address', :input_html => {  :id => 'user_email_field',:placeholder => "Enter your email..."}%>
               <label id="error_explanation1" class="error errorExplanation" style="margin-top:-10px;"></label>

          <% end %>
          <%= f.buttons do %>
            <%= f.commit_button :label => 'Send me that link', :button_html => {:class => 'submit button', :id => 'forgot_password_button', :disable_with => 'Wait...' }%>
          <% end %>

 <% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#forgot_password_button" ).click(function(e) {
  var userEmail = $("#user_email_field").val();
  var v1 = validateFirstPage();
  if(v1){
   return true;
 }else{
  return false;
}

});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( document ).on( "change", "#user_email_field", function() {
        var email = $("#user_email_field").val();
        var url = "/checkemail?checkemail="+email;
        $.get( url, function( data ) {
            $("#email_flag").val($.trim(data));
        });
    });
});
function validateFirstPage(){
    var email_flag = $.trim($("#email_flag").val());
    var userEmail = $.trim($("#user_email_field").val());
    if(email_flag =="1"){
        $("#error_explanation1").html("").fadeOut();
    }else{
        if(userEmail != "" && email_flag !="1"){
            var error_msg = "Email doesnot exists";
            $("#error_explanation1").html(error_msg).fadeIn();
        } else{
            $("#error_explanation1").html("").fadeOut();
        }
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

These are my rails server logs:

> Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-04 11:32:34 +0530
>   Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML   Rendered
>   sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/home (993.6ms)   Rendered
>   home/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)   Rendered home/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 1538ms (Views: 1157.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-04
>   11:32:36 +0530 RailsDevTweaks: Skipping ActionDispatch::Reloader hooks
>   for this request.
>
> Started GET "/checkemail?checkemail=user1@gmail.com" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2016-11-04 11:32:46 +0530 RailsDevTweaks: Skipping
>   ActionDispatch::Reloader hooks for this request. Processing by
>   AccountsController#checkemail as */*   Parameters:
>   {"checkemail"=>"user1@gmail.com"} Completed   in 1ms
>
> Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-04 11:32:52 +0530
>   RailsDevTweaks: Skipping ActionDispatch::Reloader hooks for this
>   request. Processing by SessionsController#new as */*   Rendered
>   sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/home (28.5ms)   Rendered
>   home/_header.html.erb (0.1ms)   Rendered home/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 48.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

It is not going to controller method.

Comment: write get "/checkemail" => "users#checkemail", as: :checkemail above devise _for:users

Comment: Tried. Not working..

Comment: Write the log when ajax fires

Comment: Write the checkemail  method in some other controller & then update the routes

Comment: I have written this in another controller and changed the routes but no luck.

Comment: paste the logs after change user field

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the request is not reaching the server? If so there must be some kind of JS error on the console. Maybe it is reaching the server but with the wrong format (as you are only replying to JSON but you are not specifying JSON `dataType` on your request).

Comment: @FernandoDomínguez - As mentioned in the code, I used puts for testing whether it is hitting method or no. It is not hitting and there are no errors in the log.

Comment: You do not need `puts` for that. If the request is hitting the server process you should be able to see the request on the server's log. I.e: `INFO -- : Started GET "/URL" for IP at DATE; INFO -- : Processing by CONTROLLER#METHOD as FORMAT` provided the `Rails.logger` is configured at the `:info` or lower levels. If you do not see any requests being processed something must be stopping your requests from sending. You can monitor requests on the `Network` tab of your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Added server logs, please check.

Comment: Need to modify path in the url declaration in jQuery?